# Why is the type system refusing my seemingly valid program?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-conversion

Mind this program:

```
class Convert a b where
    convert :: a -> b

data A = A deriving Show
data B = B deriving Show
data C = C deriving Show
data D = DA A | DB B | DC C deriving Show

instance Convert A A where convert A = A
instance Convert A B where convert A = B
instance Convert A C where convert A = C
instance Convert B A where convert B = A
instance Convert B B where convert B = B
instance Convert B C where convert B = C
-- There is no way to convert from C to A
instance Convert C B where convert C = B
instance Convert C C where convert C = C

get (DA x) = convert x
get (DB x) = convert x
get (DC x) = convert x

main = do
    print (get (DC C) :: B) -- Up to this line, code compiles fine.
    print (get (DB B) :: A) -- Add this line and it doesn't, regardless of having a way to convert from B to A!
```

There are instances to convert from `C` to `B` and from `B` to `A`. Yet, GHC typechecks the former, but fails for the latter. Upon inspection, seems like it isn't able to infer a generic enough type for `get`:

```
get :: (Convert A b, Convert B b, Convert C b) => D -> b
```

What I want to express is: *get :: (Convert a_contained_by_D b) => D -> b*, which seems impossible. Is there any way to implement and compile a function that does what my `get` attempts to do, without changing the rest of the setup?

Comment: It compiles fine so long as you have an instance of `Convert C A` even if it is `instance Convert C A where convert _ = error "Cannot convert from C to A"`. Is there a reason you couldn't simply do that?

Comment: And if your concern is being type safe (and that this is a partial function), you could consider making it `maybeConvert :: a -> Maybe b`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If your program *really* seemed valid to you, then you would be able to write the type of `get` that does the job you want in Haskell, not in handwave. Let me help you improve your handwave and uncover the reason you are asking for the moon on a stick.

> What I want to express is: `get :: (Convert a_contained_by_D b) => D -> b`, which seems impossible.

As stated, that's not quite as precise as you would need. Indeed, it's what Haskell gives you now, in that

```
get :: (Convert A b, Convert B b, Convert C b) => D -> b
```

any `a` which can be contained by `D` is required, one at a time, to be convertible to that `b`. And that's why you're getting classic sysadmin logic: no `D` is allowed to be gotten unless they all can `b`.

The problem is that you need to know the status not of the type which might be contained in *any* old `D`, but rather the type contained in the particular `D` that you receive as the input. Right? You want

```
print (get (DB B) :: A)  -- this to work
print (get (DC C) :: A)  -- this to fail
```

but `DB B` and `DC C` are just two different elements of `D`, and as far as the Haskell type system is concerned, within each type **everything different is the same**. If you want to discriminate between elements of `D`, then you need a `D`-pendent type. Here's how I'd write it in handwave.

```
DInner :: D -> *
DInner (DA a) = A
DInner (DB b) = B
DInner (DC c) = C

get :: forall x. pi (d :: D) -> (Convert (DInner d) x) => x
get (DA x) = convert x
get (DB x) = convert x
get (DC x) = convert x
```

where `pi` is the binding form for data which are passed at run time (unlike `forall`) but on which types may depend (unlike `->`). Now the constraint is talking not about arbitrary `D`s but the very `d :: D` in your hand, and the constraint can compute exactly what is needed by inspecting its `DInner`.

There is nothing you can say that will make it go away but my `pi`.

Sadly, whilst `pi` is rapidly descending from the sky, it has not yet landed. None the less, unlike the moon, it can be reached with a stick. No doubt you will complain that I am changing the setup, but really I am just translating your program from Haskell in approximately 2017 to Haskell in 2015. You'll `get` it back, one day, with the very type I handwaved.

There is nothing you can say, but you can *sing*.

Step 1. Switch on `DataKinds` and `KindSignatures` and build the singletons for your types (or get Richard Eisenberg to do it for you).

```
data A = A deriving Show
data Aey :: A -> * where  -- think of "-ey" as an adjectival suffix
  Aey :: Aey 'A           -- as in "tomatoey"

data B = B deriving Show
data Bey :: B -> * where
  Bey :: Bey 'B

data C = C deriving Show
data Cey :: C -> * where
  Cey :: Cey 'C

data D = DA A | DB B | DC C deriving Show
data Dey :: D -> * where
  DAey :: Aey a -> Dey (DA a)
  DBey :: Bey b -> Dey (DB b)
  DCey :: Cey c -> Dey (DC c)
```

The idea is (i) that datatypes become kinds, and (ii) that singletons characterize the type-level data which have a run time presentation. So type level `DA a` exists at run time provided `a` does, etc.

Step 2. Guess who's coming to `DInner`. Switch on `TypeFamilies`.

```
type family DInner (d :: D) :: * where
  DInner (DA a) = A
  DInner (DB b) = B
  DInner (DC c) = C
```

Step 3. Get you some `RankNTypes`, and now you can write

```
get :: forall x. forall d. Dey d -> (Convert (DInner d) x) => x
--               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- this is a plausible fake of pi (d :: D) ->
```

Step 4. Try to write `get` and screw up. We have to match on the run time evidence that the type level `d` is representable. We need that to get the type level `d` specialised in the computation of `DInner`. If we had proper `pi`, we could match on a `D` value that serves double duty, but for now, match on `Dey d` instead.

```
get (DAey x) = convert x   -- have x :: Aey a, need x :: A
get (DBey x) = convert x   -- and so on
get (DCey x) = convert x   -- and so forth
```

Maddeningly, our `x`es are now singletons, where, to `convert`, we need the underlying data. We need more of the singleton apparatus.

Step 5. Introduce and instantiate the singleton class, to "demote" type level values (as long as we know their run time representatives). Again, Richard Eisenberg's `singletons` library can Template-Haskell the boilerplate out of this, but let's see what's going on

```
class Sing (s :: k -> *) where   -- s is the singleton family for some k
  type Sung s :: *               -- Sung s is the type-level version of k
  sung :: s x -> Sung s          -- sung is the demotion function

instance Sing Aey where
  type Sung Aey = A
  sung Aey = A

instance Sing Bey where
  type Sung Bey = B
  sung Bey = B

instance Sing Cey where
  type Sung Cey = C
  sung Cey = C

instance Sing Dey where
  type Sung Dey = D
  sung (DAey aey) = DA (sung aey)
  sung (DBey bey) = DB (sung bey)
  sung (DCey cey) = DC (sung cey)
```

Step 6. Do it.

```
get :: forall x. forall d. Dey d -> (Convert (DInner d) x) => x
get (DAey x) = convert (sung x)
get (DBey x) = convert (sung x)
get (DCey x) = convert (sung x)
```

Be assured, when we have proper `pi`, those `DAey`s will be actual `DA`s and those `x`s will no longer need to be `sung`. My handwave type for `get` will be Haskell, and your code for `get` will be fine. But in the meantime

```
main = do
  print (get (DCey Cey) :: B)
  print (get (DBey Bey) :: A)
```

typechecks just fine. That's to say, your program (plus `DInner` and the correct type for `get`) seems like valid Dependent Haskell, and we're nearly there.

Comment: One day I wish I have that level of knowledge about the type system. Preferably before pi arrives! Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: One day I wish, I can write dry texts as entertaining as you do – not necessarily about Haskell…

Comment: Ahahaha "D-pendent" made my day. Absolutely brilliant answer.

Comment: On GHC 7.6, I wasn't able to use the `type family DInner (d :: D) :: * where` syntax, but instead had to convert it to using `type instance` syntax as specified on the Haskell Wiki page on [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Type_instance_declarations).  Closed type families appear to only be available in GHC 7.8+.

Answer (score 7):

For that code to work, it would have to work with any argument of the same type. That is, if

```
get (DB B) :: A
```

works then

```
get anyValueOfTypeD :: A
```

has to work, including

```
get (DC C) :: A
```

which can not work because of a missing instance from C to A.

The first line

```
get anyValueOfTypeD :: B
```

works because we do have all the three instances to convert A,B,C to B.

I do not think there's any workaround that allows you to leave the type `D` as it is. If instead you can change that, you could use e.g.

```
data D a = DA a | DB a | DC a
```

(mind that it's quite different from the original), or even the GADT

```
data D x where
  DA :: A -> D A
  DB :: B -> D B
  DC :: C -> D C
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks! I upvoted you since that is informative and correct, but I'm specifically asking for a workaround.

Comment: @Viclib I added something about that, but I'm not sure there is any workaround that allows you to use things as they are.